# Angular communication between several controller directive pairs

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I'm learning AngularJS, and I'm lost on how to solve what seems to be a simple task:

I want a way for pairs of controllers and directives to communicate and store and share data among themselves, but are kept separate from other pairs of similar controllers/directives. I want to use angular services because I have a lot of data and functions I'd like to put in the service instead of repeating myself in every controller, but the problem is that Services are singletons; What I want is several injectable instances of the same service. (Or a better practice alternative to achieve this)

**Here's an analogy**

```
A class is doing a science project about growing plants. 
Students are grouped into pairs. (a controller and a directive)
Each pair is assigned a garden (an instance of the service).
Every garden comes with tools + money for seeds (functions + data-fetchers on the service)
The students must be told where their respective gardens are (injecting the service) 
One of the students must buy and plant the seeds (the controller)
The other must maintain those seeds via watering and weeding (the directive) 
Every pair of students must work independently from other pairs
```

**Here is approximately what my code looks like (It is currently only a singleton):**

```
//Garden service
//This is only a single service. 
//I want a factory that produces these services, which I can then inject
angular.module('foo').service('garden', function(){
    this.seeds = [];

    this.buySeeds = function(seedsToBuy) { //go to store };
    this.plantSeeds = function (){...};
    this.shovel = function(){...};
    this.water = function(){...};
    this.pesticides = function(){...};
});

//Controller student
angular.module('foo').controller("controllerStudent", function($garden){
    garden.buySeeds(['tree', 'cantelope', 'cactus']);
    garden.shovel();
    garden.plantSeeds();
    garden.water();
});

//Directive student
angular.module('foo').directive("directiveStudent", function($garden){
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            garden.water();
            garden.shovel();
            garden.pesticides();
            //The garden is then presented by rendering it on the elem
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can always use event notifications to communicate. For example there are a number of services that allow you to "subscribe" and "broadcast" events. So one service or controller and broadcast a certain event that another service or controller is listening for and will pick up.

Answer (score 1):

Services and factories are singletons. There's no way around that (unless you want to switch to Angular 2). I also think you are over-thinking it a bit.

```
app.factory('GardenFactory', function() {
  function Garden() {
    this.seeds = [];

    this.buySeeds = function(seedsToBuy) { //go to store };
    this.plantSeeds = function (){...};
    this.shovel = function(){...};
    this.water = function(){...};
    this.pesticides = function(){...};
  }

  function newGarden() {
    return new Garden();
  }

  return {
    newGarden: newGarden
  }
});
```

Now you have a factory that produces gardens. You can create gardens from your controller, and if you want to persist those gardens in memory, you could add them to an array of gardens in your service:

```
// get student ID from route xx.com/students/1
app.controller('StudentCtrl', function(GardenFactory, GardenService, studentId) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  // find students garden or create new one
  $ctrl.garden = GardenService.gardens.find(function(g) {
    return g.id == studentId;  //conditional to associate garden with student
  }

  if (!garden) {
    $ctrl.garden = GardenFactory.newGarden();
    GardenService.gardens.push($ctrl.garden);  //semi-persist to service
  }

  function doStuffToGarden() {
    $ctrl.garden.buySeeds(['tree', 'cantelope', 'cactus']);
    $ctrl.garden.shovel();
    $ctrl.garden.plantSeeds();
    $ctrl.garden.water();
  }

}

app.service('GardenService', function() {
  var GardenService = this;
  GardenService.gardens = [];  //semi-persistent list of gardens
}
```